# DDD, companion object and UninitializedPropertyAccessException lateinit property bus has not been initialized

Tags: kotlin, quarkus

i'm quite new to Kotlin and having troubles understanding my issue with initalizing a vertx EventBus.

I'm using Kotlin with Quarkus (which might not be to relevant here) and Vertx in a DDD context.

I have a model, which provides a static method for sending an update. This static method creates the model and the model tries to inject the EventBus:

```
package model

import java.util.*
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped

@ApplicationScoped
class EventSet(
) {

    var events = listOf<Event>()

      @field:Default
      @Inject
      lateinit var bus: EventBus
//  kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property bus has not been initialized


    fun sendAndStore() {
        ... persist() happens here and other things

        bus.publish(UPDATE, entity)
    }

    companion object {
        const val UPDATE = "update"

        fun create(events: List<Event>): EventSet {
            if (events.isEmpty()) {
                throw Exception()
            }

            val eventSet = EventSet()
            eventSet.events = events

            return eventSet
        }
    }
}
```

When i'm running my unit test (Annotated with @QuarkusTest on the class, @Test and @TestTransaction on the function, i'm getting kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property bus has not been initialized

I don't understand it at all. My assumption was that i can inject it whenever i want. Unfortunate the constructor injection would require me to loop through it through the companion object as i was also not able to inject anything into my static method (which i assume shouldn't work anyway).

How do i debug this type of issue? I checked the quarkus dev console and the Vertx/EventBus is marked as a @Singleton bean, not sure if that makes any difference.

Thanks,

Sigi

Comment: it means that Quarkus couldn't inject.
I don't know Quakus but you can try to change the `@Inject` annotation to `@set:Inject` annotation.